# Substitute commas with dots in a BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like that if a user type "100,50" or "100.50" is the same thing. 100$ and 50 cents.

```
before_validation :strip_commas

  def strip_commas
    unless self.total_less_tax.blank?
        self.total_less_tax = total_less_tax.tgsub(",", ".").to_f
    end
  end
```

but I get this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for #<BigDecimal:7fc1ba371f08,'0.1E6',9(18)>):
  app/models/invoice.rb:17:in `strip_commas'
  app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:35:in `update'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call gsub method over the string but you are calling that on Big Decimal.So try this

```
def strip_commas
    unless self.total_less_tax.blank?
        self.total_less_tax = total_less_tax.to_s.gsub(",", ".").to_f
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes, it should work. I tried it. But it save 100.00, instead of 100.50. I don't know why. If I type 100.50 all goes right